# Crystal Reports subreports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Here is the scenario where I need help

I ve got a report - XYZ Summary Report (with embedded sub-report) and the XYZ Details report (the sub-report)

The requirement is that the XYZ Details report be a sub-report to XYZ Summary Report and also be available as a Stand Alone report through a Parameter.

Report Information:

1) A Parameter allowing the user to select the report they would like to run, either the XYZ Summary Report or the Agreement Details Report.

2) The XYZ Details Report should also be a sub-report to XYZ Summary Report which would allow the user to launch the XYZ Details Report through the XYZ Summary Report by selecting the linked Document Number.

I dont know if I am clear here. Let me know if you need more informaion

Comment: Everything is clear, except what help you actually need...

Comment: Is there a way I can give the users a Parameter allowing them to select the report they would like to run - Either the main report or the embedded sub report?

Comment: I don't see why not. Using your language of choice, make some kind of user interface asking the user which one they want, then run that rpt file.  This wouldn't be done in Crystal.  It would be done in whatever you are using to open Crystal.

Comment: If the users selected the detail (ie. sub-) report with the parameter, would you want to see it for a single document or for all documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of being able to drill down to the agreement details interactively, *and* being able to specify whether to run the report at detail or summary level makes this quite tricky - the former is implemented in Crystal using Hide functionality, while the latter requires conditional Suppression.

I recommend not doing the detail report in a subreport if you can avoid it - I find them awkward to develop and maintain. Additionally, due to the need to drill down interactively or at initial run-time, you will need to link to the subreport *twice* - once for the drill down, and once for the parameterised selection of the detail report. Consider linking the Documents table to the Agreement Details table, instead.

If you *have* to go down the subreport route, then:

- Set up your parameter with an appropriate name (eg ReportType).
- Group the main report by Document Number (if it isn't already) and place the detail items in the group header section, with the group footer section suppressed.
- Split the details section of the report into two subsections.
- Set the first details sub-section to Hide (Drill-Down OK) and add the subreport to it, with appropriate links on Document Number.
- Set the second sub-section to be conditionally suppressed (in the Section Expert dialog) based on the value of the parameter, and add the subreport to it, with appropriate links on Document Number.

Alternatively, consider the method suggested by PowerUer, in the comments.